# why mv command in verbose mode prints 'renamed' instead of 'moved' when moving file with specific directory location with -t option?

Tags: bash, shell

For Example to simulate the issue, execute following in linux (CentOS 7)

```
## create temporary destination directory
mkdir -p /tmp/b/

## create temporary file to move to destination directory
touch /tmp/a.txt

## execute move
mv -v /tmp/a.txt -t /tmp/b/
renamed '/tmp/a.txt' -> '/tmp/b/a.txt'
```

As you can see above the verbose output says "renamed" instead of moved, is there any way we can make it print to moved (without piping and replacing words using sed/awk)

```
$ /bin/mv --version
mv (GNU coreutils) 8.22
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Parker, David MacKenzie, and Jim Meyering.
```

Comment: Doesn't do that on my Centos7 system. Try upgrading coreutils.

Comment: Thanks Raman, I have posted my mv version. now its not giving text renamed.

Comment: _Why_ do you need it to print ‘moved’?! This smells like an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: @Biffen, I am specifically doing move operation of file from one directory to other directory, and not renaming a file in-place. Also, its not XY problem as I am doing simply move operation with verbose on so that on successful move command i do not need to print/echo the details.

Comment: @praxnet A move is a rename. A rename is a move. They’re the same thing (giving a file a new path). If it’s _really_ an issue and you don’t want to use `sed` et al. then the options off the top of my head are: **1** Install a different implementation of `mv` (note, though, that neither `-t` nor `-v` are part of [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/mv.html) and thus not very portable), or **2** wrap it in a (shell) function and print whatever you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

`mv`uses the underlying [rename](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html) system command. Hence it's logical that the [mv](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mv.1.html) action reports a 'rename' event.